# Assigning a string to every icon on a gridview

Tags: android, eclipse, gridview

I am creating an Android App, and I've run into this problem: I have a MainActivity that has a gridview layout. This layout is composed of 6 icons. I want 2 things for each icon

1.On click: start a new activity (I think I know how to do this)

2.On long click: show a brief string from /res/values/strings that is associated with that icon and activity

up to now I've managed to make placeholders for both actions like so:

```
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
          gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

          //for each gridview item, we want one click reaction (that creates a new Activity) and
          //a long click reaction, that shows an informative text on what this button does

            //Simple Click Action
            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //placeholder. In future will be replaced with new activity creation
                }
            });

            //Long Click Action
            gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int description, long id){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });



    }
```

Now what I want to do is in the Toast.makeText function I want to print a resource string. This string is different for each icon, and so I have a feeling it should be returned through the ImageAdapter class, which creates the gridview.
In that class, among other things, I have created an array that has each string's resource ID. So my question is:

a) How do I return that resource ID so it is usable by the MainActivity?

b) If there is a different way to do this, what is that?

I'm a newbie so it is entirely possible I've made some colossal mistake

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onItemLongClick(...)` use the `parent` parameter (which should be your GridView) and call...

```
ImageAdapter theAdapter = (ImageAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
```

In your ImageAdapter as long as you have a method to return the string resource ids, you can then use the `position` parameter (named `description` in your code) something like...

```
int resId = theAdapter.getId(description);
```

Then for the `Toast` use...

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this.getString(resId),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

On Click you will get the grid layout which you have set the `setOnItemClickListener` , Switch the `view.getId()` so that you have 6 case within swich and make transition on each case as you need , similarly toast within case in `setOnItemLongClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your useful answers.Turns out I found a different solution,that works perfectly.

Seeing how to 'access' images in a gridview you create references to them,I created an Integer array of references like this:

```
private Integer[] testDescriptions  = {
            R.string.reflexes_description,
            R.string.agility_description,
            R.string.intellect_description,
            R.string.strength_description,
            R.string.proximity_description,
            R.string.voice_description };
```

and implemented the gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener as follows:

```
gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, testDescriptions[position] ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    TextView v1 = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    if( v1 != null) v1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    toast.show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```